# Permission Denied to Install R Packages across Users

Tags: r, package, permission-denied, install.packages

I'm using the R studio server, and until recently, I have easily been able to install packages. However, suddenly, I receive this error message for any and all packages:

```
/usr/lib64/R/bin/R: line 142: /usr/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘packagename’ had non-zero exit status
```

It'll show then that the package did download, but it won't install it. I am using a corporate CRAN Mirror, and I do **not** have the ability to change security settings, etc, but I do have temporary admin access for this week.

I thought that this was an error with just my account or with the specific packages that I was trying to install, but then I found out that my coworkers are having a similar issue. They receive this error even with packages that I've previously installed at my company without any issues.

I'm aware that this is an internal thing with our CRAN Mirror, as I'm able to install packages on my personal computer. However, has anyone else had this issue? Does anyone know a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: It might be a very naive approach but if you guys have a shared version of `R` or if you are installing packages for yourself, couldn't you install them manually?

Comment: Hi @nate.edwinton, we have a shared repository of downloadable packages, but we each have our own R account. By manual installation, do you mean install.packages()? I've tried that, and that's what leads R to say that it can download it but cannot put it in that spot.

Comment: Alright. No that's not what I meant. At my former position `install.packages()` didn't work for me either due to restrictions. What worked in the end was downloading and dragging/copying the package (i.e. folder) into `C:\path\to\R-x.y.z\library`. That's what I meant by "manually".

Comment: **PS:** dependencies (i.e. package X requires package Y) have to be installed as well, so that can be a painful process iterating manually through all packages needed. But it works! (at least for me it did)

Comment: What do you mean by "temporary admin access"? Can you run `ls -l /usr/lib64/R/etc/ldpaths` in a shell and add the output to your question?